# When to use stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource in SwiftUI macOS app

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, appstore-sandbox, security-scoped-bookmarks

My SwiftUI macOS app is successfully using security scoped URLs like so below.

```
// Start accessing the security-scoped resource
if restoredURL.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource(){
    print("startAccessingSecurityScopedResource: \(restoredURL)")
}
```

Apple's documentation states:

> You must balance each call to startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
> for a given security-scoped URL with a call to
> stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource(). When you make the last balanced
> call to stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource(), you immediately lose
> access to the resource in question.

My assumption would be that I need to call `stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource` when my app exits as my app might use all resources until it is terminated. Is this the best approach and if so, how can I call this on app closure?

Comment: "my app might use all resources until it is terminated" No it mightn't. You should just bracket the actual access in `start` and `stop`.

Comment: It might and it mightn't mean the same thing. This won't work as the only point in time I know when the resource is not needed is when the app is closed.

Comment: If you don't need it now don't access it. If you need it later just access it again.

Comment: Exiting the app is usually not a defined moment. A computer can go to sleep, an app can have an App Nap or can be suddenly terminated by the system. Maybe you're able to find a moment where finish accessing the file? What kind of resources are you using? Reading/writing files? Streaming data?